# Unit testing on browser (Typescript + Webpack)

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, webpack

I want to add unit test to [this](https://github.com/s1n7ax/open-unicode-converter) project. It's a basic webpack + typescript project that will be used by another web application. Unit test should run on browser.

I tried `mocha` but just `import 'mocha'` throws compile error.
(I have test file in `project_folder/test/test.ts` which is the entry for webpack.)

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js 219:20-37
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/mocha/browser-entry.js
 @ ./test/test.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js 227:24-70
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/mocha/browser-entry.js
 @ ./test/test.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js 277:24-35
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/mocha/browser-entry.js
 @ ./test/test.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js 327:35-48
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/mocha/browser-entry.js
 @ ./test/test.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js 342:23-44
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/mocha/browser-entry.js
 @ ./test/test.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/mocha/lib/browser/growl.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../package' in 'C:\Users\s1n7ax\Documents\GitHub\open-unicode-converter\node_modules\mocha\lib\browser'
 @ ./node_modules/mocha/lib/browser/growl.js 127:13-37
 @ ./node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js
 @ ./node_modules/mocha/browser-entry.js
 @ ./test/test.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/mkdirp/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\s1n7ax\Documents\GitHub\open-unicode-converter\node_modules\mkdirp'
 @ ./node_modules/mkdirp/index.js 2:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/mocha/lib/reporters/xunit.js
 @ ./node_modules/mocha/lib/reporters/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js
 @ ./node_modules/mocha/browser-entry.js
 @ ./test/test.ts
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! open-unicode-converter@1.0.0 build: `webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the open-unicode-converter@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\s1n7ax\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-02T20_59_10_221Z-debug.log
```

If test is written without import statement, there are no compile errors, but at runtime it throws an error because method `describe` is not defined.

It's important the test to be a typescript file, because typescript classes has to be imported. Is there a library that can be used with typescript + webpack and runs on browser?

#### test/test.ts

```
import 'mocha'
describe('sample', () => {
    it('should return something', () => {
    })
});
```

#### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');


let distPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');
let srcPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
let testPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'test');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: "./test/index.test.ts",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        // this copy index.html from test/index.html to dist
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'test'), to: distPath, ignore: ['*.ts', '*.tsx', '*.js']}
        ]),
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: distPath
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        compress: true,
        port: 9000
    }
};
```

#### package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "watch": "webpack --watch",
    "test:browser": "npm run build && start http://localhost:9000 && webpack-dev-server"
}
```

Comment: How are you executing your tests exactly?

Comment: add html file to test folder that links the compiled js file.Use copy plugin to move the html to dist. start webpack-dev-server on dist folder.

Comment: If it's a js file this works perfectly with mocha web ui reports but could not find something similar that works with TS and wepack.

Comment: Ok, the way I understand it is that your production code works just alright with the import statements but the test code doesn't. That means that there is a difference in how you process them. Can you show me your config files which have relevance in the compilation of the test code (webpack config, ts config etc.)?

Comment: @DanMacák updated the details in the question.

Comment: Are you using the same tsconfig.json as in the project you posted? The repo is not up to date. Please update it or post here the tsconfig, the test html and index file.

Comment: Hello. Did you fix it?

Comment: @runia No. But I could get it working with karma.
Here is a boilerplate code:
https://github.com/s1n7ax/typescript-webpack-karma-boilerplate

Answer (score 5):

Found it.

To the top of `webpack.config.js`, add

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
```

and add to the config:

```
externals: [nodeExternals()]
```

As a side note, in `package.json` I have a.o.

```
"mocha": "6.2.1", 
"webpack": "4.41.0", 
"webpack-node-externals": "1.7.2",
```

Comment: Indeed, this solved the same problem for me, thanks